# Convert SQL Server .mdf file format

Tags: sql-server

I installed VS 11 beta and SQL Server 2012 on my development machine and at one point, I was asked to upgrade my database from version 661 (SQL Server 2008 R2) to SQL Server 2012.

I clicked yes, continued building, and now I've just realized that the file won't deploy in SQL Server 2008 R2, which is the version installed on the staging server (I don't control that machine).

I've thought of exporting the database to another format (access for instance) and reimporting it in SQL Server 2008 R2. Is that the best way to solve my problem? Is there another better way?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Why did you change your development environment so it was different from staging?

Comment: I did and I regret it; now I just need to deploy the file. VS11 is really better to work with for javascript intensive apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this 10-minute solution](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/40531) to learn how to recreate your upgraded database using "Generate SQL Server Scripts" wizard.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least four options:

- Restore your last pre-upgrade backup
- Re-create the database from scripts in source control
- Use SMO to generate scripts for all objects and re-create the database
- Use SSIS or a third-party tool to copy all database objects from one DB to another

If you opt to re-create the database from scripts, you can then use SSIS or bcp to copy the data over. But restoring a backup is by far the easiest solution and if you don't take regular backups of your development environment then this might be a good time to start.

And as someone else advised, do not develop using tools and versions that don't match your production environment.